# ActionScript 3 Newb: TextInput enter event?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I'm trying to capture the ENTER event of a TextInput like so:

```
a_txt.addEventListener(fl.events.ComponentEvent.ENTER, aEnter);

function aEnter(ComponentEvent):void 
{
    //...
}
```

There's probably something in these docs
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/TextInput.html#event:enter
which I don't quite understand because I'm getting this compile error:

```
1120: Access of undefined property fl.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure. I always use an import statement instead of qualifying with package names. 
Try adding:

```
import fl.events.ComponentEvent;
```

and then change your code to:

```
a_txt.addEventListener(ComponentEvent.ENTER, aEnter);

function aEnter(e:ComponentEvent):void 
{
    //...
}
```

Note: I also added an argument name "e" to the function call declaration.

Comment: Right. so not it compiles but just not doing anything when I press enter in the TextInput box...

Answer (score 1):

Think that you want the textEvent then tie this to your normal

```
function aEnter(e:TextEvent):void {
    if (evt.text == "\n") {
       evt.preventDefault();
       // Do some thing else??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `textInput` event, rather than the `enter`.

The `enter` event fires when the user presses the Enter/Return key.  The `textInput` event fires whenever the user types, deletes, or pastes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But this is exactly what I want. to get an event when Enter is pressed. but it doesn't work so I'm using the KEY_UP event.

Comment: Sorry, shoosh - should have asked.